# 2 divs, 1 hidden that triggers the other when hovered over

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have a div that has 2 divs within itself and the bottom div is hidden until you hover over it.

```
<div class="div_wrapper">

   <div class="div_one">Image</div>

   <div class="div_two">description</div>

</div>
```

The description is hidden until you hover over the image then it shows below it, when you hover off the image or description then they description goes back to hidden.

Comment: Sounds doable, what have you tired? Please post your code.

Comment: There will be a bunch of them, each using the same class... I want to make sure that when one opens the others will stay where they are.

This is an example of what the finished project will have to do

http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=sentient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery you can use this code:

```
var div_two = $('.div_two');
$('.div_one').mouseenter(function() {
    div_two.show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    div_two.hide();
});
```

and it should have css

```
.div_two { display: none; }
```

or if you put second div into the first one, you can show hide them using css

```
<div class="div_wrapper">
   <div class="div_one">Image
       <div class="div_two">description</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.div_two { display: none; }
.div_one:hover .div_two { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using CSS:

```
.div_two { display: none; }
.div_one:hover + .div_two { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibility:hidden` and `visible`

[Here is the CSS](http://jsbin.com/eMEV/2/edit) what you want

```
.div_two {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.div_one:hover + .div_two {
  visibility: visible;
}
```